# How to determine the fields that changed whilst editing an entity

Tags: zend-framework, entity, zend-framework3

I have a logger added that store logs when an entity is saved. What I am trying to get is how would I determine which fields have been edited for instance if I have 5 columns in one entity and I change only two columns so I would like to get the difference of only those two columns as they have been edited.

Something like `$entity->change()` so it would provide me old and new values of those two columns. I am trying to find out in zend but sadly haven't progressed any further.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? As a hint, the information you're looking for is available via the EntityManager from the UnitOfWork.

Comment: @rkeet you are the champ. Thanks but for helping out my zend bits.